# Android marquee float Images

Tags: android

I am developing application where I need random alphabets floating from left side of screen to right side of screen.
Can anybody help me, how to make floating of alphabet i.e. some image from left to right or viceversa? 
Images floats like marquee as in HTMl. they start from left side and ends at right side of screen.